# What if the Emacs stack exchange had emacs bindings?

Tags: discussion

Example:

```
C-n  - next question
C-p  - previous question
C-s  - search for question
```

Probably over the top, but I thought I'd ask.  :)

Comment: It is [feature-request], not [discussion].

Comment: Just wanted to test the waters on this zany idea before I requested it.

Comment: What about evil-mode users :) ?

Comment: I'm intrigued by this idea, and curious as to what other actions you might envision... Note that we do have [keyboard commands](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site), though the default bindings are probably not to your liking.

Comment: Conkerer (http://conkeror.org/) is a pretty cool mozilla plugin that gives you Emacs bindings.  But my most egregious oversight is that with Emacs 24.4 and eww Emacs users get Emacs bindings out of the box.  ;)

Comment: Shameless plug: http://stackapps.com/q/3950/11299

Comment: @Vamsi: They can go straight back to the pit that spawned them. :-) (I say as I wish I could use evil-mode instead of viper, but company policy prohibits installing non-approved GPL code). Though I do use vi emulation in emacs sometimes, I still know how to run emacs without it.

Comment: I'd like emacs bindings in text boxes: `Ctrl-A` for `beginning-of-line`, `Ctrl-E` for `end-of-line`, etc.

Comment: Just discovered the [firemacs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemacs/) plugin for Firefox. Now I've got emacs bindings in text boxes. Sweet!

Comment: @TreborRude you can also simply switch to OS X, and then you get Emacs keybindings in every text field across the whole OS!

Answer (score 5):

I think an official Greasemonkey or Keysnail script with this sort of functionality would be a great idea.

Comment: +1, that really sounds like something that would be best done client-side and tweakable by each user.

Answer (score 1):

Clever idea but would likely just be very intrusive. I would imagine that many other users are like myself and already have <kbd>C-n</kbd> and other bindings being used on the OS or browser level.

Comment: It doesn't need to be activated by default.